# Filling tableview from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to fill the cells of a dynamic tableview with a NSDictionary I believe, here is my method to fill the tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ResultsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSData *jsonData = self.responseFromServer;

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"myData"];
    for (NSDictionary *item in results) {
        cell.title.text =[[item objectForKey:@"title"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

If I just have

```
cell.title.text =[item objectForKey:@"title"];
```

almost works but all my titles are the same. But how it is currently I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7612940'
```

and im not sure what it means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your Dictionary is actually an array of Dictionaries each with the key @"Title".

What you are doing right now is getting the String of each element and trying to get the index of indexPath.row, but strings do not have that method.

Since you only need the object at index indexPath.row, you can replace the whole for loop with the following line of code:

```
 cell.title.text = [[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Also, as Nicholas Hart said, in order to improve performance by a lot you should put the following lines in the code when you receive the json object so that it is only done once, and make results an instance variable that can be accessed from the tableView's delegate methods:

```
NSData *jsonData = self.responseFromServer;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *results = [json objectForKey:@"myData"];
```

Comment: Also, that code is extremely inefficient.  You're deserializing the JSON data every time a new cell is needed.  You should do that once after you get the JSON from the server and store the array.

Comment: to add to what the guy above said, the cell should have a method like configureWithDictionary: and you pass in [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] and the cell then extracts the data, that way all the data for the cell is encapsulated with in the class of the cell and not the view controller of the table view